# filter data from field name on elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have written an index on Elasticsearch with following fields.

```
 $indexData = [
        'index' => 'profiles',
        'type' => 'profile',
        'body' =>[
                                'id' => $data->id,
                                'first_name' => (string)$data->first_name,
                                'last_name' => (string)$data->last_name,
                                'phone_mobile' => $data->phone_mobile,
                                'company_name' => $data->company_name,   
                             ]
                       ];
            $indexed = $profileElastic->addIndex($indexData);
```

I have managed to filter them using "more_like_this".
But i need to filter them using the Field Name.

Example: Searching value is : 456 and field is:phone_mobile.
Scenario:
First i Need to check that 'phone_mobile' column is blank or not, if it is not blank, then check whether 'phone_mobile' column has the value '456',if it is true, return the corresponding Data Set.

Anyway to do that?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What if the value of `phone_mobile` field is blank? Do you still want to return the corresponding document?

Comment: @bsarkar:nope,then i need to check the other field 'phone_work'.if both fields are blank,i will return 'empty'.If 456 is in 'phone_work' then i will return the corresponding document

Comment: In that case, you don't need to handle to missing value scenario; Elasticsearch will do it for you. It will match documents only if the value of `phone_mobile` field is `456`. If the value is something else or is missing, the document will not be returned as a result.

Comment: @bsarkar:no u didnt get my point.if mobile field is blank then i should check the work field.